# How to calculate water pressure coming out of a shut-off valve without manometre?

Tags: plumbing

I just tested, without any other sink or appliance with water running, my valve loads exactly 1 litre of water per 5 seconds in a bucket, how many bars is this? Is this a correct way of testing?

Comment: Although related to each other, pressure and flow rate are two different measurements.

Comment: do you think that a fire hose and a garden hose deliver the same amount of water per second when connected to the same water supply?

Comment: A shut-off valve doesn't really control pressure. Not directly anyway since it depends on what it's connected to.

Comment: almost enough variables: if you know the hole dimensions it can be calculated.